# Shutdown hook is not printing to console in JUnit Test executed via Maven

Tags: java, maven, logging, junit, shutdown-hook

I have a simple JUnit test which is ran by Maven through a method marked by @Test annotation. I want to place the shutdown hook into that test because I want to print some test results if the user hits CTRL-C. I code the following lines:

```
@Test
public void runTest() {
    Thread shutdownHook = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("hooked");
            ... print something via System.out.println ...
        }
    };
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(shutdownHook);

    ... run test ...

}
```

To run it I use Maven:

> mvn clean test -DtestClassName=com.MyTest

The problem is that nothing is printed. Looks like System.out.println is not working already. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Putting just that code in a `main()` prints `hooked`. Can you show a complete example that produces the same behaviour?

Comment: Works for me. I think we're going to need an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Have you written `main()` method in Your code?

Comment: As mentioned in my post, I call method annotated with @Test annotation (via Maven), I am not calling main() method.

Comment: Sorry for not complete description, it is updated now.

Comment: Please correct me, If I'm wrong. I understand that the command may be `mvn clean test -Dtest=com.MyTest` as mentions at http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

Comment: Yes, exactly, Charlee.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to write the unit test for simulating your case as the following

```
@Test
public void whenTest() {
    final Thread shutdownHook = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("hooked");
        }
    };
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(shutdownHook);
    System.out.println("Start");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Stop");
}
```

I try to execute with `mvn clean test -Dtest=MyTest` and then hit the `Ctrl+C`, It shows me as

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.test.MyTest
Start
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

If I wait for the sleeping period, it shows me as

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.test.MyTest
Start
Stop
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 10.034 sec
hooked <----- Is this your expected?

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

I hope this may help.